# How implement SqlDependency in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqldependency

Caching in MVC application with Entity Framework.

What is `SqlDependency`? How can I use `SqlDependency` in asp.net mvc? How to implement `SqlDependency` in Entity Framework with Linq-to-Entities? How scenario for create a `SqlDependency` ?

Comment: **Entity Framework** and **Linq-to-SQL** are two **separate**, distinct ORM technologies - you cannot *implement* a `SqlDependency` in Entity Framework using Linq-to-SQL - you probably mean **Linq-to-Entities** instead.

Comment: Ok. Thank You  marc_s .I mean it was that mean Linq-to-Entities .Now , How can i implement Sql Dependency with  Linq-to-Entities in EntityFrameWork ?

Comment: Check out [this interesting CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/496484/SqlDependency-with-Entity-Framework) on that topic - hope that helps you!